# Functional React: call function from imported component

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, react-component

I want to call a function from a imported component in my parent react component.

My parent component:

```
import Customer from './Customer';  

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container maxWidth="sm">
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Button onClick={Customer.showCustomers}>show customers</Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
      <Customers />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My child component (customer):

```
function Customer() {
  const [showAllCustomers, setshowAllCustomers] = useState(false);

  function showCustomers() {
    setshowAllCustomers(true);
  }
  return (
    (...)
  );
}
```

How do I call a function from another component in functional react?

Or how do I change the state from another component (if thats the better approach)

All tutorials are about object-oriented react components, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

React has a **unidirectional**, **top-down** data flow. Which means that horizontal communication is considered anti pattern. If you want to change a parent's state you should pass a handler to the child component to be executed at runtime

```
const Parent = () =>{
    const [foo, setFoo] = useState('foo')

    return <Child handler={setFoo} />
}

const Child = ({ handler }) => {
    const onClick = () =>{
        handler('baz')
    }

    return <button onClick={onClick}> Change Parent</button>
}
```

But in your case seems like the components do not have a hierarchical relationship. To share state in a decoupled way you should use `Context API`

Answer (score 2):

State is generally passed down to child components via props

```
function Child (props) {
  // Set the default state
  const [showAllCustomers, setshowAllCustomers] =  useState(props.showAllCustomers);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set the new state when props change
    setshowAllCustomers(props.showAllCustomers);
  }, [props.showAllCustomers]);

  return (
    (...)
  );
}
...
<Customer showAllCustomers={someVariable} />
```

When the `showAllCustomers` prop passed to `Customer` is changed internally the component will handle updating the local state.